# Inverse trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

Write $\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$ in the simplest form.
I have tried many ways of substitution but cannot reduce it to its simplest form.I am not sure about the denominator part.If it was $x$ it would have been quite easy

Comment: Hey Jaroslaw can you make sure that only 1+x^2 is inside the root and -1 is outside(this is the numerator)

Comment: do you mean $\sqrt{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}$ ?

Comment: OR $\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x^2}$

Comment: Not sure what you mean by simplest, but I think it is possible to show the angle is equal to $\cos^{-1} \frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2}$

Comment: If you have a triangle with sides a,b,c, and the half circumfence s = (a+b+c)/2, and angles $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, then you have (e.g. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Trigonometrie) $\alpha/2 = \tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{s^2 + bc -s(b+c)}{s(s-a)}}$. So your result is $\alpha/2$ (as a function of x) once you can identify a,b,c,s, as functions of x, from $x^2 = \frac{s^2}{s(s-a)}$, $1= \frac{bc}{s(s-a)}$ and $1/x^2= \frac{b+c}{s-a}$. Hope this works. THIS REFERS TO THE ORIGINAL OP's POST (UNEDITED).

Comment: Please make sure my edit is what you wanted.

Comment: My comment also referred to the original post where the angle was $\tan^{-1} \sqrt{1 + x^2 + (1/x^2)}$.